# Warning Prop `href` did not match

Tags: next.js, href, server-side-rendering, getstaticpaths, nextjs-dynamic-routing

I have a dynamic page route after another dynamic page route. I'm only getting this warning for the second dynamic page route.

```
Warning: Prop `href` did not match. Server: "/books/category/[category]/filter/[filter]#" Client: "/books/category/literatura-oastei/filter/ceva#"
```

How to solve this warning?

Answer (score 0):

I had to use the `fallback` property set to `blocking` inside the `getStaticPaths` function.

Example:

```
export const getStaticPaths: GetStaticPaths = async () => {
  return {
    paths: [],
    fallback: 'blocking'
  };
};
```

Read more about the `fallback` property [here](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching#the-fallback-key-required).

Comment: getStaticPaths is only allowed for dynamic SSG pages

Comment: I am also getting the same issue here at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69807274